# Swagger + javadoc generation tools (swagger-jaxrs-doclet , swagger-core) don't work in OSGI environment

Tags: java, dependencies, osgi, javadoc, swagger

There are no usage steps for non-maven projects and very little documentation on how it should be used. What are the appropriate steps for using any of those tools?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO, what have you tried to do?

Comment: For swagger-core added manually bundle dependencies jars

Comment: And in my custom Application class(Application extends DefaultResourceConfig) added necessary Resource classes and BeanConfig and i get Application cannot be instantiated error (without anything pointing to what's the problem in the stacktrace).Before that had a lot of depdencies problems ,because required jars are not bundlelised and when i made them to bundle jars there where not recognized.For swagger-jaxrs-doclet tried the gradle option but then i get multiple errors when building.All-in all followed exactly what is specified in the documentation , but that is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this page: http://amdatu.org/components/web.html

It describes how to setup REST endpoints in OSGi and dynamically expose them in Swagger (bundles for Swagger itself are also included). That's as close to a guide on this that I know.